# Wrapping last word in text with span using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `contentEditable="true"` div in which, as I type, I would like to wrap the last word before the caret in strong.

I am trying to use regex for this. I made it work for when I type of the string in the regex statically, but it does not work when I pass the word dynamically via like this:

```
textBeforeCaret.replace(`/${lastWord}$(?!.*?${lastWord})/`, '<strong>$&</strong>')
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the input here? Because `/${lastWord}$(?!.*?${lastWord})/` surrounded by backticks will look for the actual *text* surrounded by forward slashes. This might be what you actually want. Or perhaps you are trying to generate a [dynamic regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression) in which case your method is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to make a dyanmic regex, lastWord is being a variable the value of which is pulled from a string.

Comment: In that case, you need to use the `new RegExp("string with dynamic content" + someVariable)` in order to do that, as per the other question.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but if I follow the answers given there, I am unable to extract the value that I wish to wrap using "$&".

Comment: @Jacobdo  I think you should update the question showing why that does not help you.

Comment: Never mind, it does work, I was just looking at it wrong. Thank you for pointing it out.